# PostMessage mouse click to background window

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen a lot of threads about this directing to SendInput, but that doesn't work in this case.

I'm trying to send a mouse click to a certain location to a background window (game).

I can successfully send a mouse click to a background window using PostMessage, but I need to externally set the mouse position for it to work.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
```

I've also tried extending with point

```
public int MakeLParam(int LoWord, int HiWord)
{
    return (int)((HiWord << 16) | (LoWord & 0xFFFF));
}

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, MakeLParam(pt.X, pt.Y));
```

But nothing seems to work.
Is it possible to set location via PostMessage or do I have to do it externally, then click, then set cursor back to original position?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It tends to work, but accidents are pretty common.  You don't (and can't) control the keyboard state so the program might be thinking that you generated, say, Ctrl+Click.  And of course you might be getting the window handle wrong, Process.MainWindowHandle is not often correct.  Use Spy++ that have a good look, always favor a UI Automation library.

Answer (score 2):

pt.X and pt.Y means **the position in the hWnd**, not the position in the screen.
Because rest of your code works pretty well.

Comment: No sorry, that doesn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your location op point like this :

```
 PostMessage(pl, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1,MakeLParam(70,20));
        PostMessage(pl, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0,MakeLParam(71,21));
```

Comment: There is no MakeLParam for c# any idea?

Comment: `public static int MakeLParam(int x, int y) => (y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF);`